# jQuery resize div box at hover

Tags: jquery, html, resize, hover, jquery-animate

I've got two parts of code, to make 3 things:

- resize at one time only one of 6 .boxes div (with it's text content)
- make transparent .box divs which aren't selected
- show hidden .more span

**CODE:**

```
    $('.content_area div').hide();

        $(function(){
            $('.box').bind('mouseover',function() {
                $(this).addClass('up');
                $('.box').not('.up').fadeTo('normal',0.2);
            });
            $('.box').bind('mouseout',function() {
                $('.box').removeClass('up').fadeTo('normal',1);
            });
        });

        initwidth = $('.box').width();
        initHeight = $('.box').height();

        $('.box').hover(function(){
            $(this).children('.more').show();
            $(this).stop().animate({width: '220', height: '140'},{queue:false, duration:'fast'}).css('font-size', '1.2em');
        }, function(){
            $(this).children('.more').hide();
            $(this).stop().animate({width: initwidth, height: initHeight},{queue:false, duration:'fast'}).css('font-size', '1em');
        });
```

But somethings is wrong. Only first of the boxes works quite good, but it's does'nt cover up other boxes when is resized.

Effect of it You can see here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cachaito/EMBPn/17/)

And my question: is it possible, to unify this code and make it works? :-[

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is very mixed up. I looks like you pieced it together. Unfortuantly don't have the time to clean it up for you, so here are some general tips:

- For one `.hover()` does exactly the same as binding both `mouseover` and `mouseout`, so your boxes unnecessarily have two handlers for the same events. Also you are binding one in the document ready event and the other not, which is inconsistent.
- You'll need to add `stop()`s to the dimming and (un)dimming animations because thy queue up and keep going. Read the [documention](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) because you'll most likey need to set the clearQueue and jumpToEnd parameters.
- The boxes shift because you are floating them. Use absolute positioning instead (watch out for it's disadvantages!)

---

UPDATE: I've edited your code: http://jsfiddle.net/Puuxj/7/

My changes:

- Removed the class `hover` and used `.not(this)` instead. (Unless  need the class for something else...)
- Added parameters to `.stop()`.
- Used `mouseenter`/`mouseleave` instead of `mouseover`/`mouseout`.
- Positioned the elements absolute

Comment: You're great. Eveything works like a charm. Thank You for help!

Comment: This works great, but is there a way to have the other boxes size smaller as the hovered box becomes larger?